# Error Segment Fault in Flake8 running by pipenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv, flake8

In the my local enviroment `flake8 --verbose` works, but when I run `pipenv run flake8 --verbose` im my virtualenv and the result is:

```
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess     92 INFO     Loading entry-points for "flake8.extension".
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    126 INFO     Loading entry-points for "flake8.report".
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    149 INFO     Loading plugin "F" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    179 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.ambiguous_identifier" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    189 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.bare_except" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    189 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.blank_lines" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    189 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.break_after_binary_operator" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    189 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.break_before_binary_operator" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    190 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.comparison_negative" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    190 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.comparison_to_singleton" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    190 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.comparison_type" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    190 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.compound_statements" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    190 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.continued_indentation" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    190 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.explicit_line_join" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    190 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.extraneous_whitespace" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    191 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.imports_on_separate_lines" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    191 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.indentation" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    191 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.maximum_doc_length" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    191 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.maximum_line_length" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    191 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.missing_whitespace" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    191 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.missing_whitespace_after_import_keyword" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    191 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.missing_whitespace_around_operator" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    191 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.module_imports_on_top_of_file" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    192 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_async_await_keywords" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    192 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_backticks" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    192 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_has_key" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    192 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_invalid_escape_sequence" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    192 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_not_equal" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    192 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_raise_comma" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    192 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.tabs_obsolete" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    193 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.tabs_or_spaces" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    193 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.trailing_blank_lines" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    193 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.trailing_whitespace" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    193 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_around_comma" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    193 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_around_keywords" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    193 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_around_named_parameter_equals" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    194 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_around_operator" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    194 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_before_comment" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    194 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_before_parameters" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    194 INFO     Loading plugin "C90" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    195 INFO     Loading plugin "default" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    196 INFO     Loading plugin "pylint" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    196 INFO     Loading plugin "quiet-filename" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    196 INFO     Loading plugin "quiet-nothing" from entry-point.
flake8.checker            MainProcess    198 INFO     Making checkers
flake8.checker            MainProcess   1023 INFO     Checking 57 files
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can't get the core dump log of virtualenv.

flake8 version:

`3.7.8 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.5.0, pyflakes: 2.1.1) CPython 3.7.0 on Linux`

All code is running inside docker container, with python 3.7.0.

Comment: `flake8 --bug-report`:

```
{
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "dependency": "entrypoints",
      "version": "0.3"
    }
  ],
  "platform": {
    "python_implementation": "CPython",
    "python_version": "3.7.0",
    "system": "Linux"
  },
  "plugins": [
    {
      "is_local": false,
      "plugin": "mccabe",
      "version": "0.6.1"
    },
    {
      "is_local": false,
      "plugin": "pycodestyle",
      "version": "2.5.0"
    },
    {
      "is_local": false,
      "plugin": "pyflakes",
      "version": "2.1.1"
    }
  ],
  "version": "3.7.8"
}
```

Comment: I would recommend reporting bugs on a projects issue tracker, not on StackOverflow. https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues

Comment: already did that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the issue in [flake8 repository](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/591), there are some unexplained bugs in unofficial python versions. I fixed it by creating a new virtual environment, with python3.7.5 built by pyenv.